# Docker for Windows - Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker for Windows.
I tried moving my Docker Containers from the C: drive to the E: drive.
I am now getting the following error when I try to build a Docker Image:

`Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified.`

### What I have tried

Uninstalling & Reinstalling Docker.
I have tried using both the latest version (4.16.3), and version (4.13.1) since this is the version I was using prior to this issue.

### Question

What file is it missing, and how do I get this file if re-installing does not install it?

Is it possible it is not fully uninstalling, and leaving behind some corrupted file(s)?

If so, is there a way to force it to fully uninstall?

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the `data-root` setting in `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#configure-docker-with-a-configuration-file

Comment: @J.Titus I tried that but still get the same error